# Question about $\infty\cdot0$ as not defined number

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

Let's say we have this:
 $$ \infty \cdot 0 + \infty$$
since $\infty\cdot0$ is not defined can we do this: 
 $$ \infty \cdot(0 + 1) = \infty \cdot 1 = \infty $$ 
and therefore can I say $\infty\cdot0 + \infty = \infty$ ?

I guess there will be problem with doing arithmetic with $\infty\cdot0$ but I found this kind of interesting.

Comment: Nothing of this is *defined*, especially $\infty$ is not even a number. Moreover, the expression is an *indeterminate* form: There are sequences $a_n\to+\infty$, $b_n\to 0$, $c_n\to +\infty$ such that the limit behaviour of $a_nb_n+c_n$ is whatever you want. (recall that *undefined* and *indeterminate* are two independent concepts) - On the other hand, in some branches of math the convention $\infty\cdot 0=0$ makes sense.

Comment: Also, infinity is not a number. As such, it isn't defined to work with operators such as addition and multiplication

Comment: @graydad: [Actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Extended_real_number_line&oldid=609910951#Arithmetic_operations), $\infty$ *is* a number, and the operators such as addition and multiplication are (partially) extended to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Such manipulations with $\infty$ aren't mathematically permitted. Perhaps more importantly for usage of $\infty$, they don't cooperate with limits, either. For example, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, $g(x)=x$, and $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}}$. Then

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) g(x) + h(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}} = -\infty$$

yet the limit is of the form $\infty \cdot 0 + \infty$.

Comment: Manipulations aren't permitted with "infinity" because it's not a number; it does not belong to either the integers or the reals. It is a symbol indicating that a function grows beyond any bound. I write "infinity" so that we have no temptation to treat it as a number. This symbol is defined by epsilon-delta or M-delta definitions. And the equalities which are true for it have to be proved from them (for example ("infinity" times a negative number = "-infinity"). There are examples where "infinity" times 0 equals 0, others where it equals 234. So "infinity" times 0 is dependant on the context.

Comment: @Bernard: It does belong to the [extended reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Extended_real_number_line&oldid=609910951). I write $\infty$ because there is a great temptation to treat it as a number, because it *acts* enough like a number that it makes it much easier to do calculus by using it than by not. Avoiding treating $\infty$ as a mathematical object is like trying to explain that $\lim_{x \to 1} x+1 = 2$ without making reference to the number two. You *can* do it, but why would you?

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm not saying "infinity" is not a mathematical notion, I'm just saying it's not a real number. Once it's been defined and understood, there is no restriction using it. My writing "infinity" is just a pedagogical ploy which looses its utility once its defintition is understood; one way to verify that the student has understood the definition is precisely what happens when it is "divided" by itself and "multiplied" by 0 while evaluating limits.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. It is still [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). 
The results may be different. Look at the examples:

Let $(a_n), (b_n), (c_n)$ be infinity sequence such that $a_n= n^4, b_n = \frac{-1}{n}, c_n = n$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot b_n + c_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}n^4 \cdot\frac{-1}{n}+n 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-n^2) = -\infty$$

Or let $(a_n), (b_n), (c_n)$ be infinity sequence such that $a_n= n^2, b_n = \frac{-1}{n}, c_n = n$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot b_n + c_n 
= \lim_{n\to\infty}n^2 \cdot\frac{-1}{n} + n 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} (-n) + n  = 0$$

Of course in both above example $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = +\infty \wedge \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0 \wedge \lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\infty \cdot (0+1) = \infty $$

is indeed correct, assuming by $\infty$ you mean the element of the [extended real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Extended_real_number_line&oldid=609910951#Arithmetic_operations).

The problem is that you can't say

$$ \infty \cdot (0+1) = \infty \cdot 0 + \infty \cdot 1 $$

The distributive law for extended real numbers is only valid where it is defined.